# Predicting logit regression using confusion matrix problem!

Tags: logistic, classification, multinomial-logit, confusion-matrix

I keep getting the same classifications for all the  predictor regressions.  I have cut the data 
 into training and test as mentioned other problems (654 observations-training) and 218 observations-test ).

I am not sure if this is because of my code or because of the dataset itself?  I think my code is correct since it has worked before.  I do think that adding more predictors should increase the accuracy but the classification is not showing it.
First regression:

```
> q3<-glm(LFP~LLNLINC  + Age  + Nyc + fd, family= "binomial")
summary(q3)
q3a<-predict(q3, MGT1, type = "response")
summary(q3a)
blue=rep("0", 218)
blue[blue > .5] = "1"
tab <-table(blue, MGT1$LFP)
tab
```

Second regression:

```
q3<-glm(LFP~LLNLINC, family= "binomial")
summary(q3)
q3a<-predict(q3, MGT1, type = "response")
summary(q3a)
blue=rep("0", 218)
blue[blue > .5] = "1"
tab <-table(blue, MGT1$LFP)
tab
```

Both of these regression give the same classification matrix of:

```
blue.   0   1
     0  94 124
```

The training dataset is mg2
The test dataset is MGT1

What am i doing wrong?  I have added more predictors and still keep getting the same classification results.  Please advise.

Comment: You may be interested in trying a proper scoring rule like Brier score. There’s nothing special about the 0.5 cutoff.

Comment: `blue=rep("0", 218) ; blue[blue > .5] = "1"` is inevitably going to have all zeros or perhaps all `"0"`

Comment: After reading the comment by @Henry, what do you mean to do when you define “blue”?

Comment: @Henry my goal is to use the results from the logit regression to conduct on the training set.  With regards to q3a anything less than .5 should have a 0 and anything more than .5 should have a 1.  I am not sure how to do that...I think thats why i am getting all the same results.  i tried using a ifelse command..